# Mongodb : Aggregate data and apply function on each element

Tags: mongodb

I want to get a catalog with all discounted product in it.

2 documents :

```
/* Catalog schema */
{
  Catalog: {
    products: [{
      type: ObjectId,
      ref: 'Product'
    }],
  discount: {
    global: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    categories: [{
      codeCategory: String,
      discount: Number
  }]
 }
}


/* Product schema */
{ 
  reference: {
    type: String,
    index: true,
    unique: true
  },
  url_photo: {
    type: String,
    default: 'http://localhost:3001/app/img/no-picture.jpg'
  },
  category: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'Category'
  },
  short_description: String,
  long_description: String,
  price: Number,
  information: String
}
```

The discount is apply on each product from a catalog, how can i make a query in mongo to get in the catalog all product with the applied discount ?

Can i query directly to have this result ?

i already check with aggregate but i'm new with it and i can't see how can i make this.

thanks

Comment: Where are the documents stored? In the same collection? What drivers are you using, e.g. mongoose, pymongo etc.? If I had to guess I'd say you are doing a Node app with mongoose.

Comment: Catalog, Product and Category are separated collections. I'm using mongoose. You guess right it's node app.

Comment: Why do you have two `discounts` in the Catalog Schema?

Comment: Because i can have a global discount apply in on product and also discount on the product category

Comment: I understand. Thanks

Comment: How is "categories" supposed to come into play here? There is `codeCategory` as a "string", which possibly might match a field in the `Category` model? We could just apply `global`, but presumably you meant to do something with the other field as well. Apply in "override"? "In addition to the global?".

Comment: Hello Neil, thanks for your comment, you right, we can combine both discount if there are, just a mistake from my side for the codeCategory we can think we have the Category ObjectId

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below aggregation in 3.4 pipeline.

`$lookup` to pull products data for category at `catalog.products` path and use `$map` to apply discount to each product's price and include all the product fields similar to as shown for `information` field. `$addFields` overwrites the products array with discounted price.

Add category level discount if the matching product category is found in catalog. Use `$indexOfArray` to find the index of matching category, if found, use `$arrayElemAt` to find the category at that index followed by projecting discount amount else 0.

```
[
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "products",
      "localField": "catalog.products",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "catalog.products"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "catalog.products": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$catalog.products",
          "as": "product",
          "in": {
            "price": {
              "$multiply": [
                "$$product.price",
                {
                  "$add": [
                    "$catalog.discount.global",
                    {
                      "$let": {
                        "vars": {
                          "index": {
                            "$indexOfArray": [
                              "$catalog.discount.categories.codeCategory",
                              "$$product.category"
                            ]
                          }
                        },
                        "in": {
                          "$cond": [
                            {
                              "$eq": [
                                "$$index",
                                -1
                              ]
                            },
                            0,
                            {
                              "$let": {
                                "vars": {
                                  "categorydisc": {
                                    "$arrayElemAt": [
                                      "$catalog.discount.categories",
                                      "$$index"
                                    ]
                                  }
                                },
                                "in": "$$categorydisc.discount"
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            "information": "$$product.information"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Hello Veeram, thank you for you answers, i understand your request that's for a global discount, how can i match the product.category with the discount category if there is a category discount ?

Comment: You are welcome. I have added the logic to adjust for category level discount.

Comment: Wonderfull !!! 
For a newbie mongo like me you just scared me ! but i understand much more how i have to think to construct a request in mongo you're awesome man ! Is it better to store the value like you do in this request, or just make the request to get the discounted value when i need to send the catalog ? My question is based on perf

Comment: I would do it on server for simple reason that we have to lookup to get products and also requires computation to calculate discount. You can do it on client side by [`populate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) api to get products and calculate discount in javascript. You can definitively tweak aggregation pipeline to match you requirements. Feel free to create more questions and someone will be happy to answer.

Comment: I think too, however thanks for all Veeram, i'll certainly post more question on mongo, because i've made a lot of code and i know now i can compute my code directly into mongo request, that's awesome.